# Dynamically get primary color of drawable to set toolbar color

Tags: android, background-color, android-drawable, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an android app with a collapsing toolbar layout for a detailed view.  I'm trying to dynamically set the color of the toolbar, according to the primary color of the drawable that was passed in.

I know this is possible with the new material guidelines, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I started with what Akasha stated but generate is deprecated in latest version.  So I ended up doing the following.

```
// Get reference to icon drawable
Drawable iconDrawable = mPackageHelper.getAppIcon(mApp.getAppPackage());

Bitmap iconBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iconDrawable).getBitmap();

Palette iconPalette = Palette.from(iconBitmap).maximumColorCount(16).generate();

int primaryColorInt = iconPalette.getVibrantColor(0x000000);

mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(primaryColorInt);
collapsingToolbar.setBackgroundColor(primaryColorInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that, add the following dependency to your gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Then you can use the generate methods, which either take just a bitmap object or a bitmap with an integer specifying the number of colors the palette should generate.

By default, this method will try to generate 16 colors from the supplied bitmap.

```
generate(Bitmap)
generate(Bitmap, int)
```

You can read more here - [enter link description here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/extracting-colors-to-a-palette-with-android-lollipop/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I'm calling the solution from within an `onResourceReady` callback while using the `Glide` image loading library which provides a `resource: Drawable?` parameter to the callback which I then pass into to the below function to get the dominant colour. `0` is the default colour if a dominant colour is not present.

First include the correct dependency in your `build.gradle`:

`implementation "androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0"`

Then call this function with the resource in question:

```
private fun getDominantColor(resource: Drawable?): Int {
    return Palette.from((resource as BitmapDrawable).bitmap)
        .maximumColorCount(16)
        .generate().getDominantColor(0)
}
```

Then set the background of the desired view by passing the response into `targetView.setBackgroundColor(dominantColor)`